# How to create a pdf file which takes a trdp file and adds values from another JSON file

Tags: telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

I am very new to Telerik reporting and i am trying to create a c# console app which takes a simple trdp template file, inserts values into it from a JSON file during runtime and convert it into a pdf as output. Any help is appreciated as i am learning it from scratch.Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlKq8.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following C# code for console application, it takes trdp file and exports it to multiple formats, including PDF. You will find the exported documents in your console application Debug folder (if you run it in Debug configuration).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Telerik.Reporting;
using Telerik.Reporting.Processing;

namespace ConsoleApp2101
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var reportSource = new UriReportSource();
            var processor = new ReportProcessor();
            var deviceInfo = new Hashtable();

            reportSource.Uri = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\Telerik Reporting R1 2021\Report Designer\Examples\MyReport.trdp";
            
            deviceInfo.Add("DocumentTitle", "SomeOptionalTitle");

            string[] availableFormats = new string[] { "PDF", "CSV", "DOCX", "XLSX", "PPTX", "RTF" };
            
            foreach (var format in availableFormats)
            {
                var result = processor.RenderReport(format, reportSource, deviceInfo);

                if (result.HasErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result.Errors.Select(s => s.Message)));
                }
                else
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes($"MyReport.{format.ToLower()}", result.DocumentBytes);
                }
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Completed!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/programmatic-exporting-report